# Ruby on Rails and Paypal outside US

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, activemerchant

I'm using Rails 3.2.13 and I need to integrate with a payment gateway (preferably Paypal).

I've seen the railscasts of Ryan using ActiveMerchant, but I can't get it to work (I'm located in Greece), the error says that the merchant is not available in my country.

**I can't actually get API credentials for Greece as shown**
[image]

Is there a way (activemerchant or not) that I can integrate my Ruby on Rails app with Paypal  from Greece, in order to accept payments?

Thanks

Comment: There's a few railscasts about PayPal as well: http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=paypal - you need to sign up to see some of them though.

Comment: I've seen them but all of them refer to US merchants.

Comment: I'm in Australia and it's working fine. I'll add an answer with more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PayPals Merchant API works only on the countries listed above.

Answer (score 4):

There are a [few railscasts about PayPal as well](http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=paypal). Ryan uses the [paypal-recurring gem](https://github.com/fnando/paypal-recurring) which I've used successfully with an Australian account.

I think you need a Premier or Business account to use the PayPal API and IPNs.

While you're working on the payment processing you'll want to sign up for [a PayPal sandbox account](https://developer.paypal.com/) so that you know everything is working.

The code required is listed in the gem I linked to, so I'm not going to copy paste it here.

In order to request a single payment I think you can use the `request_payment` method and skip the `create_recurring_profile` method. Also, you should double check that the PayPal page users get taken to doesn't say anything about signing up for a  subscription.

Comment: First, I don't want recurring payments. Also, the sandbox api does not provide API Creds to Greek users :/

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't have to create a recurring profile with that gem, you can just ask for one payment. In fact in the railscast Ryan requests a payment (to be paid instantly) and then goes through a separate action to create a recurring profile which starts billing in +1 month.

Comment: Sure, I've updated my answer. Not sure what API creds are actually, I just opened a developer account and then various sandbox accounts with virtual money to mimick the seller and buyers.

Comment: Well,It works for Australia too! but not for Greece as you can see here https://www.dropbox.com/s/xa0yc0c87rs9rcb/Screen%20Shot%202013-04-06%20at%203.56.43%20PM.png

Answer (score 0):

here you can find paypal integration from scratch without gem

http://blog.joshsoftware.com/2013/01/08/paypal-payflow-setup-in-rails/

Comment: ask paypal about it seems the best way https://www.paypal.com/worldwide/ but don't use fake country. they will close your account and you will lost your money.